# merge rdd within an executor

Tags: performance, apache-spark, rdd

I have a spark job which aggregates data. This job has 100 tasks running in 20 executors. Each executor has 5 cores assigned. Now after aggregation, it writes data to HDFS. As each task is writing its own data, this results in 100 files on HDFS. Another issue with this approach is that increases the disk seek operation as multiple threads are writing simultaneously on a single disk.

One of the solution to avoid this problem is to repartition the data before writing it but this will mean shuffling of data and that itself is a costly operation.

Is there a way to merge RDD within an executor such that all tasks within an executor combine their data and writes a single output file?

Comment: Have you looked into the coalesce operation already?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to avoid spark serialization, I needed to write my logs to application insights directly from the executor nodes, the trick was to use @transient so spark won't serializes the object, i.e. your object stays within the executor. I borrowed the trick from this blog: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-log-in-apache-spark-f4204fad78a

Comment: @Pirooz: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually, we were looking into RDD class methods as we were working with RDDs only and it didn't have any such method. But we can convert our RDD to DataFrame and use this method assuming converting RDD to DataFrame would be less costly operation.

Comment: Coalesce is an RDD operation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#coalesce(int,%20boolean,%20scala.math.Ordering)